# Restrict content types to certain taxonomy terms

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, cck, drupal-taxonomy

I have a taxonomy set up similar to:

```
Parent Term 1
  Child 1.1
  Child 1.2
Parent Term 2
  Child 2.1
  Child 2.2
```

How can I restrict a certain content type to a certain term?

For example, I want to force "News Item" to only be in "Parent Term 2", so that on the content creation page only that taxonomy term would appear in the taxonomy select item?

Comment: This seems like a perfectly valid question; it is precisely the question I came her looking for an answer for.  Perhaps it should be moved to drupal.stackexchange.com, but it's no different from asking how to use git or thousands of other questions on this site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with [Content Taxonomy](http://drupal.org/project/content_taxonomy)'s Content Taxonomy Options module. Add a new Content Taxonomy field, and use the Select widget. In the field settings, under the *Advanced settings for hierarchical vocabularies* field group, select the Parent Term you want to use for that field.